# Get the application ID while running a MapReduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Is there any way to fetch the application ID when running - for example - the *wordcount* example with the `yarn` command?

I wish to initiate a job from another process with the `yarn` command, and monitor the status of the job through the YARN REST API.

(Using Hadoop 2.4.0)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `yarn application -list` command to get the list of all the applications.

Specifically if you want to get the list of all the applications, which are currently in `RUNNING` state, you can execute the following command:

```
yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING
```

If you already know the application ID, then you can query the status of the application using the following command:

```
yarn application -status <application ID>
```

For e.g.

```
yarn application -status application_1448359154956_0001
```

I get following application report (in this case application was `KILLED` by user):

```
Application Report :
Application-Id : application_1448359154956_0001
Application-Name : distcp
Application-Type : MAPREDUCE
User : mballur
Queue : default
Start-Time : 1448359237581
Finish-Time : 1448359419592
Progress : 100%
State : KILLED
Final-State : KILLED
Tracking-URL : http://mballur.fareast.corp.microsoft.com:8088/cluster/ap
p/application_1448359154956_0001
RPC Port : -1
AM Host : N/A
Aggregate Resource Allocation : 1652876 MB-seconds, 1337 vcore-seconds
Log Aggregation Status : NOT_START
Diagnostics : Application killed by user.
```

You can parse this output to get `State` and `Progress` of the application.

Answer (score -3):

Checkout http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html. Should have a something to get the application ID you need.

Comment: Misread the question. Still trying to understand exactly what you are trying to do. But the application command with filter -appState should get you the app you are trying to monitor. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application